# Integrating of $\int_0^{\pi} x^2 \big( \sin(x)\big)^{2t+1} e^{a\cos(x)} dx$

Tags: integration

> Integrate
> $$\int_0^{\pi} x^2 \big( \sin(x)\big)^{2t+1} e^{a\cos(x)} dx , \qquad t\in\mathbb Z^+, a\in\mathbb R$$

My attempts were to solve it by using integration by parts and I repeated the process, but it ultimately led me nowhere. I look forward to your experience. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $\int_0^\pi e^{a\cos(x)}\;dx$ is (using a Bessel function) $\pi J_0(a)$.  So there is no reason to think your integral is an elementary function.  Maple does not evaluate your integral even with Bessel functions.

Comment: Even for $t=0$ and $a=1$ there is no solution.

Comment: Is there a numerical solution?

Comment: without the $x^2$, you can just make a substitution and its not too nasty but I'm afraid this may only be possible using numerical methods

Comment: It suffice to integrate
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(t)
&=\int_{0}^{\pi}\cos(tx)
\sin^{2\nu}(x)e^{a\cos x}\text{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(tx)
\sin^{2\nu}(x)\sinh(a\cos x)\text{d}x\\
&=2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(tx)
\sin^{2\nu}(x)\cos(x)^{2n+1}\text{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
The inner one can be expressed by some hypergeometric ${}_2F_1$ terms. Then take differentiations twice, it will give us the required result. But I am sure about that the result don't have simpler expression.